# SwiftUI dragging ScrollView flickers as the keyboard is dismissing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

When I develop the feature that allows users drag ScrollView to dismiss keyboard in SwiftUI, I find that if you drag ScrollView as the keyboard is dismissing, the ScrollView will flicker. That will destroy the experience of the feature.

Here's the video and minimal code example:

[Video](https://cdn.catrefuse.com/RPReplay_Final1644590984.mp4)

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  
  @State var text:String = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      Rectangle()
        .frame(height: 300)
      TextField("test", text: $text)
        .padding()
        .background(Color.gray)
        .padding()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your code works fine with me, no flicker when dismissing the keyboard. Is some code missing?

Comment: I suspect there is as the OP describes a feature that dismiss keyboard on a drag not he scrollview. There is nothing of the sort here in code.

Comment: @ChrisR You should drag the ScrollView manually as the keyboard is dismissing. I didn't add the drag-to-dismiss code in the example.

Answer (score 1):

It's caused because the keyboard forces the view to resize.
Add

`.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)`
to the bottom of your view to solve this issue